# Por que o compilador cria arquivos .class repetidos?

Tags: java, compilação

Tenho observado que quando o compilador do java compila alguma classe que tenha algum componente do swing/awt, ele cria uma outra ou até várias classes de mesmo nome, com um `$` seguido de uma numeração.

Fiz um código simples para checar se era coisa do netbeans ou se realmente era o compilador e ao compilar o código abaixo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tela {

    public Tela(){

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tela 1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("teste");
        JButton button = new JButton("botao");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            new DialogTela(frame, true);
            }

        });
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p.add(label);
        p.add(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(p);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tela();
            }
        });
    }

    class DialogTela{

        public DialogTela(Frame f, boolean modal){

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(f,modal);

            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("teste");
            dialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            p.add(label);
            dialog.getContentPane().add(p);

            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }   
}
```

Resultado após compilar:

[image: print dos arquivos .class]

Até entendo ele ter criado o `Tela$DialogTela.class`, acredito que por ser uma classe interna, mas não entendi porque o compilador criou o `Tela$1.class`e o `Tela$2.class`, além do próprio `Tela.class`.

Pra desencargo de consciência, criei outra classe chamada `Teste`, onde faço apenas uma chamada pra um `JOptionPane`(que também é do pacote swing):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Teste{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "teste", "Teste", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

e foi gerado apenas o `Teste.class`.

Pra que seriam aquelas classes repetidas que o compilador criou da mesma classe? É alguma particularidade da API do swing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Um arquivo .java pode gerar vários arquivos .class. O compilador Java (javac) gera mais de um .class quando existe uma classe interna e/ou classe anônima interna, sendo que para este último as classes anônimas são numeradas, essa é a razão para Tela$1.class e Tela$2.class.

No exemplo da pergunta:

- **Tela.class** ---> Tela.java
- **Tela$DialogTela.class** ---> Class interna
  (inner class), chamada DialogTela
- **Tela$1.class** ---> Classe anônima interna (`new Runnable() {...}`)
- **Tela$2.class** ---> Classe anônima interna (`new ActionListener() {...}`)

No caso das classes anônimas internas, não saberia dizer exatamente qual é o *Tela$1.class* ou *Tela$2.class*. Precisa saber a ordem com que as coisas são compiladas pelo Javac. O exemplo acima, portanto, foi arbitrário, a título de exemplo.

Um detalhe: esse mecanismo do compilador do Java é aplicado em qualquer tipo de aplicação que seja compilada por ele (Swing, J2EE, Linha de comando, etc).

Comment: Então a resposta da pergunta já estava nela :D Fiquei tão decepcionado comigo quando li sua resposta que fiz um teste baseado na resposta, usando Thread, sem swing e sem nada, e o resultado foi exatamente esse.

Comment: @diegofm, no momento que você estava comentando eu editei a minha resposta exatamente dizendo que isso é do Java em geral. Pura coincidência. :-) Não fique decepcionado, sua pergunta está muito bem escrita e servirá pra muita gente.