# Posso ter problemas de performance juntando várias classes a um único arquivo?

Tags: java, android

Assistindo muitos tutoriais e vídeo aulas, sempre vejo que é criado um arquivo java para cada ação/classe. Assim como indico na imagem abaixo com a seta numero 1 amarela.

Mas como meu aplicativo está ficando enorme, estou começando a colocar as classes dentro de um único arquivo, já que cada classe será utilizada apenas na opção que for aberta. Assim como indico com as setas em cores vermelhas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora a questão é: estou fazendo isso de forma correta? Ou isto poderá deixar meu aplicativo mais lento e devo fazer com cada classe separada em cada arquivo como era antes mesmo?

Minha ideia é simplificar o melhor possível mantendo uma boa velocidade de execução.

Comment: Acredito que nesse caso a performance não é afetada, e sim a organização do seu projeto, isso não vale somente para aplicativos mobile, e sim para qualquer tipo de projeto

Comment: Entendo, eu também acho que pela lógica não deveria afetar. Acho ruim do java, que é necessário digitar umas 15 linhas pra uma ação simples. Em quanto no php a mesma ação poderia ser feita com 1 única linha. Qualquer aplicativo simples que criamos se enche de classes. Então por isso fiz essa pergunta, para que eu não tenha problemas no futuro quanto tiver muitos usuários utilizando. Obrigado por responder amigo.

Comment: Não se preocupe antecipadamente com desempenho. Isso vai te levar a evitar padrões de código perfeitamente válidos e escrever código menos legível. Escreva o código mais correto e limpo que puder. Se surgirem problemas de desempenho, faça as medidas para determinar onde está o problema. Raramente vai ser nesse tipo de detalhe.

Comment: Tambem  é preciso levar e consideração que o java irá [criar arquivos de bytecodes separados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137622/28595) para cada classe, mesmo que estejam em um unico arquivo, talvez isso afete apenas o tempo de compilação, mas a performance após compilado acredito que nao.

Comment: @Artícuno Do jeito que ele fez compila? Se não me engano o Java só aceita uma classe pública (e N não-públicas) por arquivo, e não N classes públicas (não falando de inner classes).

Comment: @Piovezan não sei te falar porque a imagem é bloqueada para mim. Se for  duas classes publicas, você está certo, não compila mesmo, mas da pra empilhar varias classes num arquivo, sem ser todas dentro da classe publica, eu mesmo [ja fiz isso aqui varias vezes em respostas](https://github.com/diegofelipem/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/swing/examples7/MainTelas.java)

Comment: @PabloAlmeida obrigado por responder. Eu só estou me preocupando agora pra evitar o máximo ter que ficar fazendo alterações depois. Prefiro ja ir programando do jeito certo. Estou colocando tudo na mesma classe exatamente pra evitar bagunças com muitos arquivos, mas sempre tem aquele medo de ter que refazer tudo novamente. kkk,

Comment: @Articuno obrigado por responder, acho que na nova versão do android studio isso ja acontece, da uma olhada: https://image.ibb.co/gQWMYH/2018_02_21_13_54_54.jpg, creio que seja isso que você está dizendo. Mas se não afeta a performance ta ótimo, a compilação por enquanto esta sendo rápida.

Comment: @Piovezan creio que você esteja certo sobre varias classes publicas no mesmo arquivo, ele da mesmo um erro, mas quando cria uma classe dentro da outra, ai funciona de boa. Da uma olhada neste print onde da erro e onde funciona: http://image.ibb.co/i5WwYH/2018_02_21_14_05_05.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A visão geral da [resposta do @Pagotti](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277777/64969) está certa, se feita do jeito certo. Porém, suas classes não são estáticas. Se não é estático, é de instância. Sabe o que acontece quando algo é de instância? Ele precisa guardar a referência para a instância original.

Como posso provar que é de instância? Nas classes internas, você consegue fazer `FragmentList.this`, que retorna a referência ao objeto de `FragmentList` que instanciou a classe, por exemplo, `EquipeList`.

Internamente, como funciona? Todos os construtores das classes internas recebem um argumento a mais [[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html#implcit_and_synthetic)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html#implcit_and_synthetic), o `FragmentList.this`. Portanto, criar um objeto de uma classe de "instância" impõe um argumento a mais na pilha do que um construtor normal de classe auto-contida. Também tem a questão que cada objeto vai fazer uma referência a mais, portanto vai ter mais um campo dentro de cada objeto.

Qual o impacto real disso? Só medindo, eu acho que é quase nada para aplicações normais. Saiba que jogos **não são aplicações normais**. Um jogo precisa ser otimizado de modo que o usuário não tenha a percepção de *framemiss*. Isso significa que você só tem 16ms entre dois quadros para processar tudo e fornecer uma nova tela (tempo válido para Android, não lembro em outras plataformas). **Mas** normalmente não é com *essa* escovação de bit que você consegue dar a performance necessária.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo. Não estou fazendo um jogo não. É um aplicativo simples de classificados. Porém tem muitas telas como FAQ, Sobre a empresa, Formulário de Contato, Festas e Eventos e etc. A questão que comecei a fazer assim é que cada item que chama uma lista no banco de dados ou um link em json, eu preciso criar uma classe adapter para popular a lista. Então em vez de criar um arquivo para cada adapter, estou fazendo ele dentro da classe responsável por cada layout. Ja que é algo simples e creio q não seja pesado para uma performance. Mas entendi sua resposta também. Obrigado ^^

Comment: Há alguma referência para o que está dizendo, Jefferson?

Comment: @CaiqueC. leitura de bytecode? Também tem a parte do GWT explicando que classes internas não são serializáveis automaticamente porque não tem construtor padrão, pois todos os construtores recebem um argumento implícito. Vou procurar uma referência mais canônica, entretanto

Comment: @CaiqueC. ainda não canônico, mas em outra referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70613/4438007

Comment: @CaiqueC. referência canônica: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html#implcit_and_synthetic ; vou encaixar na resposta agora

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, o que disse está correto. A única coisa que não consigo entender é a relação disso tudo com ter N classes num mesmo arquivo.

Comment: @CaiqueC. depende da organização interna das classes. Se elas forem classes aninhadas (estratégia mais amplamente usada), o aninhamento estático evita parâmetros implícitos. Caso contrário (estratégia menos comum), serão classes dentro da mesma unidade de compilação, então apenas uma pode ser pública e para todos os efeitos não é de instância (portanto se aproxima da classe aninhada estática). Tem mais aprofundamento aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23580793/4438007 . Eu particularmente acho que, como a própria Oracle não cita essa segunda estratégia, é seguro ignorá-la

Answer (score 3):

### Não tem diferença no desempenho final

Separar um arquivo para cada classe é uma boa prática para deixar código mais legível e organizado. O resultado da execução do programa depois de compilado será o mesmo se você tiver as classes em um arquivo único ou em vários arquivos separados.

Comment: Se as classes forem estáticas =/ classe não estática/de instância o desempenho é pior um pouco

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, creio que para o que estou fazendo, e por tudo que me responderam nesse tópico, acho que realmente não terei problemas com o desempenho. Ja fico mais tranquilo para seguir a programação. Obrigado ^^

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu tinha entendido que a dúvida dele não se referia a estrutura das classes e sim se colocava em arquivos separados ou tudo junto. Mas lendo a sua resposta entendi que na verdade a questão vai além porque no caso do Java no mesmo arquivo só cabe classe interna, acho que se não for interna ele nem compila.

Comment: @Pagotti, o caso de ter várias classes como raiz tem o mesmo efeito de serem classes estáticas. Talvez tenha problema de visibilidade, não lembro ao certo como lidar com isso. Só sei que é tão raro ver isso que eu mesmo me esqueço da existência.